# Depth and Size error for 2d image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to copy a source image to the rest image in OpenCV Python.

```
cv.SetImageROI(resImg, (x,y,w,h))
cropImg = cv.CreateImage((w,h), 8, 3)
cv.Copy(resImg,cropImg)
cv.ResetImageROI(resImg)
```

Output:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size) in cvCopy, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/copy.cpp, line 558
cv2.error: src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size
```

For Some images, i am getting above error but for some Images it's working , any Idea?

Comment: Any specific reason for using old `cv` API? Any issue with `cv2` ?

Comment: I found one segmentation code online, So I am just editing the code without writing it again.

Comment: check if your `resImg` and `cropImg` have the same number of channels, i.e., make sure they are **both** grayscale (1 channel), *or* RGB (3 channels). In your case - make sure `resImg` has 3 channels.